# How can I create a fully distributable C# application with a proper install?

Tags: c#, winforms, installation

Is it possible to create a fully-distributable application using C# that installs in a "proper" location (i.e. C:\Program Files\MyAppName) using only Visual Studio?

I'm new to creating stand-alone apps and I have created a first simple test app, but now wish to develop a home inventory-type application.  It requires the distributable SQL Server database (which I used in my test app), and I would like it to install to a "normal" location.  Right now, it seems to install to C:\Users\%Username%\AppData\Local\Apps\2.0.

Can this be done with C#, or does it require some 3rd party installation creation package?

Comment: How are you 'installing' your application now?

Comment: I build it using VS (**Build --> Build MyFileName**) and it puts a bunch of files into a folder, one of which is "Setup.exe".  When I run that, on either the same computer or a completely different one, it installs the app and it's visible in the **Start --> All Programs** menu.  However, all the files it installs appear to be in the Local\Apps\2.0 folder.

Comment: Umm... so you've configured your applicaiton to create an installer?  Visual Studio doesn't create a setup.exe file by default when you build.  Is this a ClickOnce application?

Comment: @A.R. It sounds like a ClickOnce, which does create a setup.exe

Comment: Yes, it does have files that are of "click once" type.  I'm really new to this type of app building, I mainly do .net websites.  So if that's the wrong approach, just let me know.

Comment: What version of Visual Studio are you using? Creating installer projects was bundled in to 2008 and earlier, removed in 2012, then re-added as an [extension in 2013](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/9abe329c-9bba-44a1-be59-0fbf6151054d).

Comment: I've got 2010.  So it's a separate project?  I was hoping it was just some settings I was missing.

Answer (score 3):

As long as they don't rely on assemblies in the GAC, etc. .NET applications are standalone / "fully-distributable" by default.  The most common way that I install my applications to other machines is by copying the output folder, (bin\Release for example) to my desired install location.  For applications that are to be downloaded off of a website, zipping the folder should be sufficient, and the user can unzip to any location that they wish.

Comment: My desired result is to put this up on, say, download.cnet.com and let people download and install it for free, so I don't want to rely on them having to be that knowledgeable.  Is it possible to create one file; MyAppName.exe, and have that file put everything where it belongs?  Or is this even beyond the scope of C# and I should be looking at a different language?  I know there are plenty of EXE files that do exactly that, I'm just trying to recreate that functionality (if possible).

Comment: I like this one:  http://www.jrsoftware.org/isinfo.php.  Just pack up your folder into an installer that it creates.  Should be flexible enough to meet your needs.